# AWS Lightsail Django Bitnami : Operational Error- Attempt to write read only database

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, server, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I have a website that is completely functional in development, however, I'm unable to configure the server permissions for my `.sqlite3`database file, so as to allow database changes eg Login, and Register. I'm using the bitnami stack for Django on AWS lightsail and I would appreciate help on the matter. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami developer here!

Django stack uses Apache as its server, which is configured to delegate those requests to a Python daemon process.

It may be the case that if you were using a `venv` or extra python configuration, you'd have to adapt the virtual host configuration file to take that into account.

```sh
$ cat /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/vhosts/myapp-http-vhost.conf
...
SGIDaemonProcess APPNAME python-home=/opt/bitnami/python python-path=/opt/bitnami/projects/APPNAME
...
```

Regards!